# PHP eAccelerator: shmmax error

Tags: php, apache, eaccelerator

I installed eAccelerator and if I uncomment `extension="eaccelerator.so"` in PHP and restart Apache if fails and in the error.log stands

> eAccelerator: shmmax should be at least 2MB

If I set `eaccelerator.shm_max="4M"` it even don't work and if I set it so `eaccelerator.shm_max="0"` it also don't work. I get everytime the mentioned error.
I'm using PHP 5.2.4 and (latest) eAccelerator 0.9.6.1. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but `shm_max` != `shmmax` it seems to me the latter might be a OS setting as described e.g. in [this forum thread](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=16192)

Comment: what's the output of the following command on your system?
sysctl -a | grep shmmax

Comment: Output is: `kernel.shmmax = 33554432`

Answer (score 0):

A :
check available space at

/tmp/eaccelerator/

B:
try increase shm_max @ php.ini

eaccelerator.shm_max="0"

from 0 to 2 or 4

C:
try uninstall EAccelerator

/scripts/phpextensionmgr uninstall EAccelerator